Where to locate workflow definition for GitHub ruleset required workflows?
I'm trying to create a required workflow, i.e. a workflow declared in a host repo that can be run against other repos via an org level ruleset.
Originally I was working off of this doc that stated:

Required workflows can be stored in any repository folder and are not restricted to the .github/workflows folder like normal workflows.

However, when I tried to place my workflows in a subfolder it prevented me from creating a ruleset using the workflow:

I relocated my workflow to the .github/workflows directory and was able to create the ruleset. However, my workflow is now running against the repository hosting it like any other workflow would. This workflow is not meant to execute against the host, only repositories targeted by the ruleset.
Where do I define my workflow such that I can use it in a ruleset as a required workflow and it will not be executed against the host repository?

The documentation seems to be incorrect for this. As a workaround, you can set a job-level if condition with if: github.repository != 'org/hostrepo'

FWIW, at some point in time, it was definitely possible to store a required workflow in an arbitrary directory.

@BenjaminW. I may do that. The only reason I avoided it is because every required workflow would then show as an item during pull requests against the host repository.

The ruleset does have to go in the ./github/workflows directory.
To get around the issue of the workflow running in the host repository (without adding conditions to all the jobs which results in skipped checks in the Pull Request):
In the required workflow host repo:

Navigate to the Actions tab
Select the workflow
Click the ellipsis
Select Disable workflow



Have you tried placing required workflow in?
org/host-repo/.github/workflows-host/org-ruleset-workflow.yml@main


Based on the error above it looks like it is requiring the workflow to be specifically in the .github/workflows directory. I haven't tried that one specifically, but can't find any docs that would indicate that directory is "special".

Could this be a GitHub Enterprise Server version issue?

I'm using Enterprise Cloud.

Perhaps that is the answer then.

At this time I have added a condition to the workflow jobs per Per Benjamin W.'s comment:
if: ${{ github.repository != 'org/repo' }}

I don't like this solution because it will show a skipped check for every required workflow in the host repo at PR time. As I plan to implement multiple required workflows, this will look sloppy and misleading in the UI during PRs. Hopefully a better solution will come along.
